# CSS: h1, h2, h3 Multiple Selectors + separate h2 ...Order Matters?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So here's the problem I have. I wanted to be efficient and set all of my header tags to be the same font-family. So I used the code below. However it only appears to work when the multiple selector code is AFTER the single h2 code.

If i place the multi-selector code BEFORE the h2 code then it ignores it completely. Any thoughts as to what I am missing? Here's a link to the test page:

http://www.jasonkoprowski.com/test/JK_Test.html

I want the header to display using 'Crimson Text' font but seems to be defaulting to 'Times New Roman' (not even sure where it's getting this from actually. It works find when i put the h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 code after but not before.  I guess I could just put it after the h2 tag code and be done with it but I want to make sure that I understand the root cause of the issue:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 { 
   font-family:"Crimson Text", "Lucida Sans Unicode","Times New Roman", serif;
}


h2 {
  color:#232323;
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:500;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  line-height:1.1em;
  margin:30px 0;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:42px;
}
```

To add even more to my confusion, when I added the code to Code Pen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EDpJg) it looks to be rendering correctly...so something wrong on my site?

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Koprowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with your selectors or the ordering of your rules (although [in general it does matter](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html) sometimes), it's with the `<style>` tags at the beginning and end of your stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

and

```
</style>
<!--CSS END-->
```

These belong in an HTML page, but not in a CSS sheet. Furthermore, the start tag is interfering with your `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5` rule. You should remove them.